# efficient way substracting two very large data frames with different number of rows (matching XYZ)

Tags: r, dataframe, parallel-processing, large-data

I have pairs of very large data.frames df1 & df2 (>500,000 rows) with different number of rows, both containing the same 4 columns (X,Y,Z coordinates and a count attribute). Doomie example:

```
df1<-data.frame(x=c(3,5,2,4),y=c(8,5,7,6),z=c(13,15,12,10),
      count=c(10,20,4,12))
df2<-data.frame(x=c(4,3,6),y=c(6,9,8),z=c(10,13,15),count=c(4,7,3))
```

I want to subtract the count column (`df1$count - df2$count`) only for rows matching XYZ (same spatial point). I found a way to do it by using the function `merge() {base}`, but it is slow and the df's are very large.

Any tip how could I make it any faster??? Should I try to introduce a parallel processing? Any tip how to do it in parallel with such example without the need to cut the df's in chunks??

Thanks.

My implementation:

```
df3<-merge(df1,df2,by.x=c("x","y", "z"),by.y=c("x","y", "z"),all.x=T,all.y=TRUE)
df3[is.na(df3$count.x),4]<-0
df3[is.na(df3$count.y),5]<-0
df3$countdif<-df3$count.y-df3$count.x
```

***NEW EDIT.*** **ANSWER:** The 2 suggestions in the answer by Akrun worked fine. The first one turned out 2x faster in the microbenchmark test, and is working also for my large data frames. here the benchmark of them:

Using dplyr {}

```
dodplyr<- function (a,b){
    dfN<- full_join(a,b, by=c('x', 'y', 'z')) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), 0)), 
                starts_with('count')) %>%  
        mutate(countdif= count.y-count.x)
    dfN<-select(dfN,-count.x,-count.y)
    return(dfN)
}
```

and Using data.table {}

```
dodata.table<-function(a,b){
    setDT(a)
    setDT(b)
    DT <- merge(a,b, by=c('x', 'y', 'z'), all=TRUE)
    for(j in 4:5){set(DT, i=which(is.na(DT[[j]])), j=j, value=0)}
    DT[, countdif:= count.y-count.x]
    DT[,c("count.x","count.y"):=NULL]
    return(DT)
}
```

And the microbenchmark:

```
times <- microbenchmark( dodplyr(df1,df2), dodata.table(df1,df2), times=1e3)
> times
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      dodplyr(df1, df2) 2.374164 2.489710 2.978814 2.590829 2.704017 18.15356  1000
 dodata.table(df1, df2) 5.094271 5.308994 6.458764 5.534259 5.675328 37.23370  1000
```

HOWEVER I could not compare them with my implementation using merge{base} with dfs. I tried to include it but I get errors when calling the microbenchmark. Here what I tried:

```
domerge<- function(a,b){
  dfm<-merge(a,b,by.x=c("x","y", "z"),by.y=c("x","y", "z"),all.x=T,all.y=TRUE)
  dfm[is.na(dfm$count.x),4]<-0
  dfm[is.na(dfm$count.y),5]<-0
  dfm$countdif<-dfm$count.y-dfm$count.x
  dfm<-dfm[,c(1:3,6)]
  return(dfm)
}
```

That works when calling it e.g. `df3<-domerge(df1,df2)` but it gives error when microbenchmarking:

```
> times <- microbenchmark(domerge(df1,df2), dodplyr(df1,df2), dodata.table(df1,df2), times=1e3)

Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in merge.data.table(a, b, by.x = c("x", "y", "z"), by.y = c("x",  : 
  Can not match keys in x and y to automatically determine appropriate `by` parameter. Please set `by` value explicitly.
```

Comment: `merge()` has quite a few improvements in current devel, 1.9.5. But benchmarks on us/ms scales are relatively meaningless for tools designed to scale on large data, and you're very likely just measuring overhead of `[.data.table` calls.

Comment: @ Arun, thanks a lot for your comment. Sorry for my ignorance but what you mean with: "benchmarks on us/ms scales are relatively meaningless for tools designed to scale on large data".
On the other hand do you think is it then possible the real performance of the data.table approach for this case could be faster than the dplyr one?, how could I know which on is more performing other than the benchmarking? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the `full_join` from `dplyr` would be faster with respect to `merge` (not tested though). After we are done with the `full_join`, the 'NAs' in the 'count' columns are `replace`d by '0' using `mutate_each` and then we create the 'countdif' column using `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
dfN <- full_join(df1,df2, by=c('x', 'y', 'z')) %>%
           mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), 0)), 
                           starts_with('count')) %>%  
           mutate(countdif= count.y-count.x) 
dfN
#  x y  z count.x count.y countdif
#1 3 8 13      10       0      -10
#2 5 5 15      20       0      -20
#3 2 7 12       4       0       -4
#4 4 6 10      12       4       -8
#5 3 9 13       0       7        7
#6 6 8 15       0       3        3
```

Or a possible approach using `merge.data.table` from `data.table`.  We convert both the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, `setDT(df2)`).  Then, use `merge.data.table` to do the `full-join`.  We replace the 'NA' values in the 'count' columns to 0 (here it is 4th and 5th column) in a `for` loop with `set` (`set` is very efficient as it doesn't have the `.[data.table` overhead.  We assign (`:=`) new column 'countdif` as the difference between 'count.y' and 'count.x'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
DT <- merge(df1, df2, by=c('x', 'y', 'z'), all=TRUE)

for(j in 4:5){
         set(DT, i=which(is.na(DT[[j]])), j=j, value=0)
  }
DT[, countdif:= count.y-count.x]
DT
#   x y  z count.x count.y countdif
#1: 2 7 12       4       0       -4
#2: 3 8 13      10       0      -10
#3: 3 9 13       0       7        7
#4: 4 6 10      12       4       -8
#5: 5 5 15      20       0      -20
#6: 6 8 15       0       3        3
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. any hint which one might be faster dplyr or data.table? I am not familiar with how to measure the performance of 2 alternatives.

Comment: @josetanago I would assume the `data.table` version to be fast as the last two steps `replacing NA with 0` and `assigning`  a new column is very fast.  For measuring the timings, you can use `?system.time` or `?microbenchmark` from `library(microbenchmark)`

Comment: @josetanago Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I did the microbenchmark with your two suggestions and got dplyr faster by half of time. Where shall I post the result of it? here as a comment? editing my question? or adding an answer?

Comment: @josetanago Thanks for benchmarking.  Could you please edit your post and update the result.  It is interesting though.  BTW, are those methods faster than the `merge`?

Answer (score 0):

You got to create an algorithm that substract like this example:

(if they have an independant ALU)

```
y=1
while y <= "end.of.y"
 Core one > df1={1,1,y} - df2={1,1,y}
 //you subtract the y until the end of y column is reached 
 //saving in another matrix called as you want, then
 Core two > df1={1,1,y+1} - df2={1,1,y+1}
 ...
 Core eight > df1={1,1,y+7} - df2={1,1,y+7}
 y=y+8 
endwhile
```

And do the same for the other axis x and z (nested loop cycle). Untill the end of them are reached.

If you have 4 ALUs only in the processor, you have to do the same but using only 4 'cores'

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo. In your implementation I don't understand very well how to first match the XYZ from the 2 dfs that is the condition to substract the 4th column of both (and only this one). please, Could you explain me a bit more?